# Scala: find character occurrences from a file

Tags: scala

**Problem:** 
suppose, I have a text file containing data like

```
TATTGCTTTGTGCTCTCACCTCTGATTTTACTGGGGGCTGTCCCCCACCACCGTCTCGCTCTCTCTGTCA
AAGAGTTAACTTACAGCTCCAATTCATAAAGTTCCTGGGCAATTAGGAGTGTTTAAATCCAAACCCCTCA
GATGGCTCTCTAACTCGCCTGACAAATTTACCCGGACTCCTACAGCTATGCATATGATTGTTTACAGCCT
```

And I want to find occurrences of character 'A', 'T', 'AAA' , etc. in it.

**My Approach**

```
  val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath)
  val lines = source.getLines().filter(char => char != '\n')

  for (line <- lines) {
    val aList = line.filter(ele => ele == 'A')
    println(aList)

  }
```

**This will give me output like**

```
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

**My Question**
How can I find total count of occurrences of 'A', 'T', 'AAA' etc. here? can I use map reduce functions for that? How?

Comment: You're almost there, just add a counter and sum up the length of the lists.

Comment: what's wrong with val y = x.partition(_ == 'A')._1.length

Comment: Does it count as an occurrence if it spans multiple lines? (e.g. `AA\nA`)

Comment: @jwvh yes. Is it possible?

Comment: Tricky. You probably want `TAAAAT` to count as a single occurrence of `AAA` (with an extra `A` at one end) and not as 2 occurrences (that happen to overlap). It might have been advantageous if you had spelled out these requirements originally.

Comment: @jwvh yes too tricky!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is even a shorter way:

```
lines.map(_.count(_ == 'A')).sum
```

This counts all `A` of each line, and sums up the result.

By the way there is no `filter` needed here:

```
val lines = source.getLines()
```

And as *Leo C* mentioned in his comment, if you start with `Source.fromFile(filePath)` it can be just like this:

```
 source.count(_ == 'A')
```

As *SoleQuantum* mentions in his comment he wants call count more than once. The problem here is that `source` is a `BufferedSource` which is not a *Collection*, but just an ***Iterator***, which can only be used (iterated) once.

So if you want to use the `source` mire than once you have to translate it first to a *Collection*.

Your example:

```
  val stream = Source.fromResource("yourdata").mkString
  stream.count(_ == 'A') // 48
  stream.count(_ == 'T') // 65
```

*Remark: String is a Collection of Chars.*

For more information check: [iterators](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/iterators.html)

And here is the solution to get the count for all Chars:

```
stream.toSeq
    .filterNot(_ == '\n')       // filter new lines
    .groupBy(identity)          // group by each char
    .view.mapValues(_.length)   // count each group > HashMap(T -> TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT, A -> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, G -> GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG, C -> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC)
    .toMap                      // Map(T -> 65, A -> 48, G -> 36, C -> 61)
```

Or as suggested by *jwvh*:

```
stream
    .filterNot(_ == '\n') 
    .groupMapReduce(identity)(_=>1)(_+_))
```

This is **Scala 2.13**, let me know if you have problems  with your Scala version.

**Ok after the last update of the question:**

```
stream.toSeq
    .filterNot(_ == '\n')       // filter new lines
    .foldLeft(("", Map.empty[String, Int])){case ((a, m), c ) =>
        if(a.contains(c))
          (a + c, m)
        else
          (s"$c", 
           m.updated(a, m.get(a).map(_ + 1).getOrElse(1)))
      }._2 // you only want the Map -> HashMap( -> 1, CCCC -> 1, A -> 25, GGG -> 1, AA -> 4, GG -> 3, GGGGG -> 1, AAA -> 5, CCC -> 1, TTTT -> 1, T -> 34, CC -> 9, TTT -> 4, G -> 22, CCCCC -> 1, C -> 31, TT -> 7)
```

Short explanation:

- The solution uses a `foldLeft`.
- The initial value is a pair:

  - a String that holds the actual characters (none to start)
  - a Map with the Strings and their count (empty at the start)
- We have 2 main cases:

  - the character is the same we have a already a String.
    Just add the character to the actual String.
  - the character is different. Update the Map with the actual String; the new character is the now the actual String.

Quite complex, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: If count of 'A' over the entire file is wanted, it can be as simple as `source.count(_ == 'A')`.  There is no need to do `getLines`.

Comment: @LeoC @pme `source.count(_ == 'A')` will produce correct output but if I write `source.count(_ == 'T')` as a next statement then it will output `0`

Comment: @SoleQuantum  use `source.mkString` if you want to use the Stream more than once. I will add an explaionation to my answer.

Comment: @pme but `source.mkString` may throw `OutLOfMemory` error in case of huge file so i doubt it's worthy

Comment: @pme my objective is to find occurrence of all characters like - A, T, C etc

Comment: @SoleQuantum this looks again a bit different;) - check my updated answer

Comment: If **2.13** is acceptable then isn't `.groupMapReduce(identity)(_=>1)(_+_)` just about all you need?

Comment: @jwvh thanks, especially for `identity` which I could not remember when writing my answer;)

Comment: @SoleQuantum please update your question - it clearly states that you only wanted to count 'A'

Comment: @SoleQuantum check my updated answer - it gets more complex with each round, make sure the next time to ask exact what you want.

Comment: @pme the deployment server has scala 2.12.3 and I can not update it. And I'll keep your advice in mind next question onward - for sure

Comment: @SoleQuantum the last version that should solve all your problems - works also on 2.12;)

Comment: @pme as you suggested, if I write, `val m = stream.toSeq.filterNot(_ == '\n').groupBy(identity).view.mapValues(_.length).toMap` then it's giving me error like `value mapValues is not a member of scala.collection.IterableView[(Char, Seq[Char]),scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Seq[Char]]]`

Comment: @SoleQuantum no you should take only the last version - that is the only one that works with 2.12 `.....foldLeft(("", Map.empty[String, Int])){....`

Comment: @pme one last question, I want to use `val m = stream.toSeq.filterNot(_ == '\n').groupBy(identity).view.mapValues(_.length).toMap` then how can I eleminate that error in 2.12?

Comment: @SoleQuantum just remove the `view`, like `stream.toSeq.filterNot(_ == '\n').groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)` / `toMap` is not needed.

Comment: @pme, I just posted new question with same data, same approach. But this time I need to find out something different. Can you answer? [link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181863/scala-hlow-to-find-maximum-continuous-occurrence-of-a-character-in-file)

Answer (score 1):

Since `scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath)` produces stream of `char`s you can use `count(Char => Boolean)` function directly on your `source` object.

```
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath)
val result = source.count(_ == 'A')
```

Comment: but I want all like `source.count(_ == 'A')` then `source.count(_ == 'T')` then `source.count(_ == 'C')`, etc. Using your solution I'll get only first. The rest results would be `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count by doing the following:

```
lines.flatten.filter(_ == 'A').size
```

Comment: `.sum` will throw if the file happens to be empty.

Comment: @senjin.hajrulahovic, tried with `lines.map(_.filter(_ == 'A')).map(_.size).reduce(_ + _)`.  But it throws exception like - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.reduceLeft
 at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeft(Tra

Comment: I forgot that reduce also fails in case of an empty list.  If you're just interested in the count then its better to use a combination of flatten and size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Partition method and then just use length on it.

```
val y = x.partition(_ == 'A')._1.length
```

Comment: You traverse the file contents once for the `partition()` and the `._1` part again for the length. Not as bad as the `.map(_.filter()).map(_.size)).sum` solution, but not as clean as `.count()`.

Answer (score 0):

In general regular expressions are a very good tool to find sequences of characters in a string.

You can use the `r` method, [defined with an implicit conversion over strings](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/collection/StringOps.html#r(groupNames:String*):scala.util.matching.Regex), to turn a string into a pattern, e.g.

```
val pattern = "AAA".r
```

Using it is then fairly easy. Assuming your sample input

```
val input =
  """TATTGCTTTGTGCTCTCACCTCTGATTTTACTGGGGGCTGTCCCCCACCACCGTCTCGCTCTCTCTGTCA
  AAGAGTTAACTTACAGCTCCAATTCATAAAGTTCCTGGGCAATTAGGAGTGTTTAAATCCAAACCCCTCA
  GATGGCTCTCTAACTCGCCTGACAAATTTACCCGGACTCCTACAGCTATGCATATGATTGTTTACAGCCT"""
```

Counting the number of occurrences of a pattern is straightforward and very readable:

```
pattern.findAllIn(input).size // returns 4
```

The iterator returned by regular expressions operations can also be used for more complex operations using the `matchData` method, e.g. printing the index of each match:

```
pattern.                      // this code would print the following lines
  findAllIn(input).           // 98
  matchData.                  // 125
  map(_.start).               // 131
  foreach(println)            // 165
```

You can read more on `Regex` in Scala on the API docs ([here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) for version 2.13.1)

Comment: and suppose i want to find occurrence of a,t,c,g in map then how should i write?

Comment: You can still use regular expressions to this end, so you can use `[ATGC]` as your regex and find them all in one go.

Comment: You can read more on regular expressions on the JVM here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: You can play around with regular expressions to find the one that works for you with this handy online tool: https://regexr.com/