# Scala: how to find maximum continuous occurrence of a character in file?

Tags: scala

**Problem:** 
suppose, I have a text file containing data like

```
TATTGCTTTGTGCTCTCACCTCTGATTTTACTGGGGGCTGTCCCCCACCACCGTCTCGCTCTCTCTGTCA
AAGAGTTAACTTACAGCTCCAATTCATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTAGGAGTGTTTAAATCCAAACCCCTCA
GATGGCTCTCTAACTCGCCTGACAAATTTACCCGGACTCCTACAGCTATGCATATGATTGTTTACAGCCT
```

And I want to find MAXIMUM continuous occurrences of character 'A' like, 'AAAA..', etc. And at which position in file - like in which line.

**What should be the approach for it?**

```
  val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath)
  val lines = source.getLines().filter(char => char != '\n')

  for (line <- lines) {
    //how should I do that
  }
```

**This will give me output like**

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA(line 2)
```

**My Question**
How can I find MAXIMUM continuous occurrences of character 'A' like, 'AAAA..', etc. in position in file - like in which line?

Comment: I would recommend you to start by defining exactly what is the output that you expect as well as to think how would you solve such problem if you were the computer, think what would be the basic algorithm step by step and then try to code that, if you have problems with that last part you can come back and edit this question to provide more details.

Comment: Your current approach doesn't count characters as continuous if they span multiple lines. Is this expected?

Comment: @Tom actually I'm asking the right approach. like what shouldI do for it? let me edit my question

Comment: @Tom I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Ok first here how to handle one line:

```
 def maxInLine(line: String) = line.split("[B-Z]").toList.max
```

We can use a Regex to split the line. (`List(, A, , , , AA, , , , , , ,`)
For other Character the Regex looks different.

As the maximum of a String is the one with the most characters (if they are the same), we just need `max` to get the maximum characters of a line.

And then get the max of all lines:

```
val (as, index) = allLines
                    .map(maxInLine)               // Get the max of a Line
                    .zipWithIndex                 // zip it - for the line number
                    .maxBy { case (l, _) => l }   // get the line that has the most A
```

The result can we then use like this:

```
println(s"$as (${as.length} As / Line ${index + 1})")
```

Which prints: `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (15 As / Line 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some way to find the longest String composed by only one character (so not only looking for 'A's but can easily be adapted if needed) :

I'm folding on each character, computing some arbitrarly defined `State`. This State will keep in memory the longest sequence and the current sequence, with respective starting positions.

```
val stream = "TATTGCTTTGTGCTCTCACCTCTGATTTTACTGGGGGCTGTCCCCCACCACCGTCTCGCTCTCTCTGTCAAAGAGTTAACTTACAGCTCCAATTCATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTAGGAGTGTTTAAATCCAAACCCCTCAGATGGCTCTCTAACTCGCCTGACAAATTTACCCGGACTCCTACAGCTATGCATATGATTGTTTACAGCCT".toStream

case class State(longest: String, current: String, longestPos: Int, currentPos: Int)

val state = stream.foldLeft(State("","", 1, 1)){case (state, c) =>
  val (current: String, curpos: Int) = if(state.current.forall(_ == c)) (state.current :+ c, state.currentPos) else (c.toString, state.currentPos+state.current.length)
  if(state.longest.length < current.length)
    State(current, current, curpos, curpos)
  else State(state.longest, current, state.longestPos, curpos)
}

println(s"longest sequence : '${state.longest}' with ${state.longest.length} chars, at position ${state.longestPos}")
```

Output :

```
longest sequence : 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' with 15 chars, at position 98
```